# Appending JSON return data into html not working

Tags: php, json, ajax

I have this script which returns subcategory list of a item category.

But it seems working only if  `j.lenth =='0'` (json data =[]).

If json returns a data (Example :[{optionValue: 1, optionDisplay: 'Sub cat 1'}]) script's `else` part is not working.

```
<script>
$(function () {
$("select#Category").change(function () {
    $.getJSON("/content/category.php", {
        id: $(this).val()
    },

    function (j) {
        var options = '';
        if (j.length == '0') {
            options = '<option value="-1">There is no sub category</option>';
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
                options += '<option value="' + j[i].optionValue + '">' + j[i].optionDisplay + '</option>';
            }
        }
        $("#sub").html(options);
        $('#intSubRubriek option:first').attr('selected', 'selected');
    });
});
```

});

category.php

```
 <?php

$aCats = $oCon->dbFetchSmarty ( "SELECT * FROM `sub_category` WHERE parent_id = '"  . $_GET['id'] . "' ");

if ( isset ( $_GET['id'] ) ) 
{
    echo "[";
    for ( $i = 0; $i < sizeof ( $aCats ); $i ++ ) 
    {
        if($i == 0)
        {
            echo "{optionValue: " . $aCats[$i]['sub_id'] . ", optionDisplay: '" .  $aCats[$i]['sub_name'] . "'}";
        }
        else
        {
            echo ", {optionValue: " . $aCats[$i]['sub_id'] . ", optionDisplay: '" .  $aCats[$i]['sub_name'] . "'}";
    }
}
echo "]";
} 
else 
{
    echo "[{optionValue: 0, optionDisplay: '". $_LANG['content']['categorien_1'] ."'}]";
}

?>
```

Comment: Define **'not working'** ...

Comment: @Naruto `<option></option>` not getting appended(actually it's not created if JSON returns a data);. Even if I add alert("hooray") in the else clause its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[{optionValue: 1, optionDisplay: 'Sub cat 1'}]
```

is not valid JSON. It should be

```
[{ "optionValue": "1", "optionDisplay": "Sub cat 1" }]
```

That is why your success handler is executed only when you get an empty response, `[]`. When you get a response with items, it is in fact the error handler not the success handler that is being triggered, because the response not is holding valid JSON. So change your code to

```
if ($i == 0) {
    echo '{ "optionValue" : "'.$aCats[$i]['sub_id'].'", "optionDisplay": "'.$aCats[$i]['sub_name'].'"}';
} else {
    echo ',{ "optionValue" : "'.$aCats[$i]['sub_id'].'", "optionDisplay": "'.$aCats[$i]['sub_name'].'"}';
}
```